# Simple way to insert line to particular position in file

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I need to insert string to text file,
for example, before first line from the end.

```
STRINGS=`wc -l $OLDFILE \
    | awk '{print $1-1}' \
    | sed "s/$DOLLAR/+/g" \
    | tr -d \\\n \
    | sed "s/+$DOLLAR//" \
    | bc`
ADDFILE=$3
head -n $STRINGS $OLDFILE > $NEWFILE
cat $ADDFILE >> $NEWFILE
tail -n 1 $OLDFILE >> $NEWFILE
```

Can you suggest simple way to perform that?
Thanks

Comment: I think you mean "particular" (or perhaps "arbitrary"). "Random" means something else.

Comment: Although, to be fair, Random Access Memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'f==1{print last}{last=$0;f=1}END{print "NEW WORD\n"$0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit simpler:

```
(tail -1 "$OLDFILE"; echo "hello there"; tac "$OLDFILE" | tail -n +2) | tac > "$NEWFILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (pure-bash) solution:

```
prev=
print=
IFS=
while read -r line; do
    if [ "$print" ]; then
        echo "$prev"
    fi
    print=1
    prev="$line"
done < "$OLDFILE"
echo "hello there"
echo "$prev"
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the awk script above, but in bash.

Comment: This does not work. It removes a lot of white space and backslashes from the input file.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple one:

```
head -n -1 "$OLDFILE"
echo "hello there"
tail -1 "$OLDFILE"
```

Comment: In my system head does not support negative offset :(,
so I must calculate it myself

Comment: ok, then see my other two solutions (which I deleted after posting this one, but undeleted now).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one I could think of

```
sed -i "$ i Text to add" file.txt
```